# Scrape Data within HTML Tags Perl

Tags: html, perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize

I'm writing a web scraper, and am a Perl novice. I'm using `HTML::TreeBuilder` to get the data I need, but I've run into a case I'm not sure how to handle. Here's some sample HTML:

```
<div class="anything" val="20" name="matchup">someUniqueData</div>
```

I want to extract the `val` from this HTML tag. I've been using `findvalues()` to do most of my work, but I don't know if this can pull data from inside tags. I've glossed over the documentation unsuccessfully. Is there a simple solution for this type of scrape?

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried, and we can help you from there.  You might also want to do more than "gloss over the documentation."  For more on HTML parsing, see http://htmlparsing.com/perl

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because what I know how to try, `findvalues()`, gets data outside tags. I looked at the entire TreeBuilder documentation, and didn't see a method that would work. I'm not going to search every Perl module in existence for a method when I could ask if anyone else has had this issue. So if you're not going to be helpful, just go somewhere else.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`attr`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Element#attr) in HTML::Element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need (using `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`):

```
my ($val) = $tree->findvalues('//div[@class="anything"]/@val');
```

Comment: CSS selector equivalent: `use Web::Query 'wq'; print wq('<html><div class="anything" val="20" name="matchup">someUniqueData</div>')->find('div.anything')->attr('val');`